# Alternative for AppendTo[]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

as I'm well aware, using `AppendTo[]` for large lists isn't recommended as the function gets progressively slower with each appending done.

Lots of suggestions talk about using `Reap[]` and `Sow[]`, however the ones I found don't deal with nested lists. 
My question is relatively simple, how to substitute `AppendTo[]` with `Reap[], Sow[]` as directly as possible?

Specific information regarding my problem: I would like to append data in form of

```
data = {{x},{y}}
```

to a list, so after a few iterations, the list would look something like

```
list = {{{x1},{y1}},{{x2},{y2}},{{x3},{y3}}}
```

My solution works for only 1 iteration, and then breaks apart because of increasing use of `Flatten[]`, so it's obviously a non-working solution. Of course, I'm open to other alternatives, faster than `AppendTo[]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, reposted it there.

Comment: Then, to comply with SO etiquette, you should delete it here.  Cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: FYI: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44901/363